# Cannot start Tizen Package Manager on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, tizen

Last time I installed and run normal Tizen Package Manager. But I uninstall and reinstall it because I have some problem with Connect to real device. But after I install Tizen Package again, it throw exception:
[image]

Message: "64-Bit Java Development Kit is not install"

Step I have done but it's not success

- Install OpenJDK, SDK.
- Reinstall Tizen Extension for Visual Studio.
- Follow step: https://docs.tizen.org/application/vstools/install/

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution, that I need to delete TizenSDK folder, and then reinstall Tizen Extension. That work for me.